# How to add to the beginning of each line of a large file (>100GB) the index of that line with Python?

Tags: python-3.x, file

**some_file.txt:** (berore)

```
one
two
three
four
five
...
```

How can I effectively modify large file in Python?

```
with open("some_file.txt", "r+") as file:
    for idx, line in enumerate(file.readlines()):
        file.writeline(f'{idx} {line}') # something like this
```

**some_file.txt:** (after)

```
1 one
2 two
3 three
4 four
5 five
...
```

Comment: You have to open the other file with a different name. Read from the first file, write into the second file. Then rename the new file into the old file.

Answer (score 1):

Don't try to load your entire file in memory, because the file may be too large for that. Instead, read line by line:

```
with open('input.txt') as inp, open('output.txt', 'w') as out:
    idx = 1
    for line in inp:
        out.write(f'{idx} {line}'
        idx += 1
```

You can't insert into the middle of a file without re-writing it. This is an operating system thing, not a Python thing.

Answer (score 0):

Use `pathlib` for path manipulation. Rename the original file. Then copy it to a new file, adding the line numbers as you go. Keep the old file until you verify the new file is correct.

Open files are iterable, so you can use `enumerate()` on them directly without having to use `readlines()` first. The second argument to `enumerate()` is the number to start the count with. So the loop below will number the lines starting with 1.

```
from pathlib import Path

target = Path("some_file.txt")

# rename the file with ".old" suffix
original = target.rename(target.with_suffix(".old"))

with original.open("r") as source, target.open("w") as sink:
    for line_no, line in enumerate(source, 1):
        sink.writeline(f'{line_no} {line}')
```